# having an issue using ExecuteScalar function in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to use `ExecuteScalar` function by checking the backend table whether one of the columns is set to “NO”.  If one of the columns is set to NO then I want to call `SendEmail` function, else I want to call `Delete_Record` function.  My problem is that it is always calling the `Delete_Record` function and never calls the `SendEmail` function.  The data type for the `Post_ID` is varchar and I don’t know if this has anything to do with; I just can’t seem to figure out what is going on.  Can someone please help?
Here is my code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from MyTable WHERE Post_ID =@Post_ID And (Column1='No' OR Column2='No' OR Column3='No')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Post_ID;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    Int32 result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result == 1)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
      else
     {
       Delete_Record();
     }
```

Comment: Can it be more then one? can you check `result` value?

Comment: What if the result is 0 (no records matching the criteria) or greater than 1 (more than 1 record matching)?

Comment: Are you expecting the result to be exactly `1`, may be there are more records satisfying your condition, put a break point to see what is being returned, or just change your condition to `(result >= 1)`

Comment: All what i am trying to do is check if any of these columns has the word "NO" if one of them has NO then i want to send an email else call the other function.

Comment: either column1/column2 or column3 can be set to NO or all of them can have NO.  thanks

Comment: One of them means that there can be more than one, right?

Comment: What happens when you run that query directly in DB (SSMS/SQL Server I assume?)

Comment: Epsilon, u were right it was more than one. once i changed to this: result >=1 then everything worked fine.  thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it could be more than one, you should change your condition to

```
    if (result >= 1)
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
      else
     {
       Delete_Record();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you could get more than 1 record back. Either use  "if (result >=1 )" or try

"SELECT ***1*** from MyTable WHERE Post_ID =@Post_ID And (Column1='No' OR Column2='No' OR Column3='No')"

Answer (score 0):

try this. will definitely work.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT count(*) from MyTable WHERE Post_ID =@Post_ID And (Column1='No' OR Column2='No' OR Column3='No')", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Post_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Post_ID;
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader rd=cmd.ExecuteReader()

    if (rd.Read())
    {
        SendEmail();
    }
      else
     {
       Delete_Record();
     }
```